# Magento 2 Installation error in Ubuntu system

Tags: installation, ubuntu, magento2.3.4

In Ubantu System xampp server using install the Magento 2 erorr!

1.Magento 2.3.4 admin penal does not open gives Error 404 .

[image]

2.When I open the terminal and hit the magento command like:
`php bin/magento c:c` then gives error!

[image]

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigOptionsList.php:179
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigModel.php(71): Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList->getOptions()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ConfigSetCommand.php(64): Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigModel->getAvailableOptions()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(77): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ConfigSetCommand->configure()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ConfigSetCommand.php(54): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->__construct()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/vendor/zendframework/zend-di/src/Di.php(512): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ConfigSetCommand->__construct(Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigModel), Object(Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList), Object(Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig))
# in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento234/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigOptionsList.php on line 179
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @asik miyani did you check .htaccess exist in root ot pub folder or not if not exist then add it will work

Answer (score 0):

i have issues faced after long time ago

Then I solved it just adding the .htaccess file in root folder.

Magento root file .htaccess code :-

```
###############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

############################################
## Add custom headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Now run this command :-

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/generation/*
```

And second Solutions:-

For Linux edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

To edit this file use **sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf** command

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After this run command

> sudo service apache2 restart

Thanks.

Comment: I have install xampp into Ubuntu, magento working find and command give error which I have attached screen shot

Comment: frontend and backend both are working ??

Comment: Yes working but what about the command Interface issue? You can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPYN1.png

Comment: Please send your error text words

Comment: I have updated please check

Comment: please check this link :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14660/files/3745fa8d08fe9e51fdcdb6053e2a54eeee254181

Answer (score 0):

Backup and replace **Setup** folder on the root with already installed magento 2.* setup folder.

Then run the **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** and other.It will be fix.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have already solved the problem.

Comment: What did you do to fix it @RasikMiyani. My admin and frontend are working but I can't run anything on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem using  below command

```
sudo apt-get –purge remove php-common

sudo apt-get install php-common php-mysql php-cli
```

after execute these 2 commands, restart Apache and MYSQL.

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**