# "Undefined class constant 'PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY' " what is this error? I am using magento 2.3 and php 7.3

Tags: magento2, php, php-pdo

When I try to enable a new module by `php bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_HelloWorld` command this comes.

Comment: Please check my answer may be used for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305004/magento-2-installation-error-in-ubuntu-system/316619#316619